# How to find multiple column counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called Tag Lists

Fields are list_id, person_id, company_id

```
id | List_id | Person_id | Company_id
-------------------------------------
1  | L1      | P1        | C1
2  | L1      | P2        | C1
3  | L1      | p3        | C3
4  | L2      | P4        | C4
5  | L2      | P5        | C5
```

How can I get a output like the below one. Is this possible in a Single MySQL Query?

```
id | List_id | Person_count | Company_count
-------------------------------------------
1  | L1      | 3            | 2
2  | L2      | 2            | 2
```

Using a normal group by on single column I am able to find either person_count or company_count for the lists.

```
Select list_id, count(person_id) from tag_lists group by list_id
```

Comment: Anything wrong with using `COUNT` twice? `SELECT list_id, COUNT(person_id), COUNT(company_id) FROM tag_lists GROUP BY list_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use DISTINCT and two COUNT() methods:

```
SE list_id, COUNT(DISTINCT person_id), COUNT(DISTINCT company_id) FROM tag_lists GROUP BY list_id
```

This way you should get your desired output. I did not test this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
Select list_id, count(distinct person_id),count(distinct Company_id) from tag_lists group by list_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
Select list_id, count(Distinct person_id), count(Distinct Company_id) 
from tag_lists 
group by list_id
```